# Why max netlink msg size is limited to 16k

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, kernel-module, netlink

I am observing that max Netlink msg that my kernel module can send to
user app is close to 16K.

For larger sizes, `genlmsg_unicast()` succeeds but my app does not receive data.

In my user app, I am using `libnl`

I have tried increasing RECV buffer size in my user app but that does
not help.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

This was answered on the Linux net-dev mailing list: http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg431592.html

Comment: Is it also the case from user to kernel space? I observed something similar in that cast as well.